# Facebook (2015) - how can I hide my activity from ticker?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-groups

Is there any way to hide my activity - comments, posts and like - that I made in Facebook closed groups?

For example, if I join a Facebook group "Pets", I don't want my friends to see my activity in this group (I don't want to appear my comments, posts and likes in the ticker).

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are a member of a closed group, only the people inside that group will be able to see your comments, posts, and likes.  If your friends are not members of that closed group, then your comments/posts/likes will not appear on your friends' news feeds (and neither will your joining of that group).  But if you have any friends who have joined that group, then they will be able to see anything you do in the group.

Here is a [Facebook article](https://www.facebook.com/help/220336891328465) that describes the privacy of Facebook groups.  It says the following about closed groups:

> Who can see what members post in the group?  Only current members
>
> Who can see stories about the group on Facebook (like in News Feed and search)?  Only current members

Comment: Thank you @pacoverflow. So I automatically suppose that my posts/likes/comments are hidden from my friends' thicker (if they're not members of that group), right? One more thing - if I join a closed group, this information will appear in friends' thicker?

Comment: @user984621 Yes, your posts/likes/comments in the closed group will not appear on your friends' news feeds.  I also tested joining a closed group and I checked my mother's Facebook profile (who is friends with me on Facebook), and it did not tell her that I joined the closed group.

Comment: Is it possible to hide posts and comments in an open group from a friend who is also in that group?